# Like a jenkins wall-board but in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

After years of jenkins, I use Gitlab in my new work

A feature which I miss is the wall: a board who display the state of various job and process ( runing, stopped , success, failed)

Is there anything similar in gitlab?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [monitoror](https://monitoror.com/documentation/#gitlab). You can monitor your pipeline status with it.